# Creating Geomedia mdb files without ArcMap Interoperability extension

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, gdal, fme-form, geomedia

For our day-to-day tasks, my team uses ArcGIS Pro. Unfortunately, we work in a very niche industry with a very niche software which requires most of the other teams to use GeoMedia .mdb files.

As of now, we are using the ArcMap FME Data Interoperability Extension to convert our GDB packages into MDB files that they can use. For many reasons, we are trying to move away from having to use the Data Interoperability Extension, and instead would prefer to create the MDB files outside of it.

GDAL/OGR2OGR has been something I've been exploring, but they no longer support GeoMedia MDB files. I was able to [find some drivers here](https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal-extra-drivers) that add the functionality back, but cannot figure out for the life of me how to install them. It appears they need to be built in Linux.

How can I natively build GeoMedia MDB files without the ArcMap FME Data Interoperability Extension?

Comment: GDAL has never supported writing GeoMedia files, the driver was read-only. At least for Windows it is still possible to find and download old GDAL versions which have the driver but that would not help you. I fear you must either continue to use the Interoperability Extension or acquire a license for standalone FME. A sustainable solution would be spend the money for making the niche software to support some open data format.

Comment: @user30184 Thank you for your answer. I had no idea that the driver was read-only, so you have saved me a lot of wasted time trying to build it. Unfortunately standalone FME dropped support for GeoMedia mdb too, as it is 32-bit and they are moving to exclusively 64-bit. Unfortunately, yours is the answer I was expecting but I figured I might as well ask!